# Control installation depending on platform in MSIX package

Tags: windows, uwp, package, desktop, msix

I have added desktop extension to my UWP app that gives some extra functionality if it runs on Windows 10 desktop platforms. But for other platforms it won't be used. Hence I want to make sure that the desktop extension isn't installed on other platforms thereby saving users some disk space. I have looked into [app extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-an-extension) but it won't be viable for my use cases since the UWP app and desktop component communicate via named pipes and memory mapped files. Is there any other way I can control the installation of desktop component depending upon the platform it is being installed??

### Update 1

From researching further I have found that this should be possible with [optional packages/related sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages), to be accurate related sets for my scenario. The examples provided in docs only show scenarios for packaging uwp apps as related sets and no example for packaging win32 apps as related sets was given. Is there any way to package a win32 application as related sets??

Comment: It is not supported to install your UWP app while not install its desktop extensions.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT is there any reason why it is not supported?? Desktop extension will only be used in desktop platform, so it makes sense to not install it in other platforms. Is there any plan to support this feature, if not is there any place I can request for this feature??

Comment: It is not supported for UWP to control the installing process. You could go to the **Feedback Hub** and submit a feedback to request the feature.